# Ibeacons and advertising

Tags: ios, connection, alert, ads, ibeacon

How exactly to ibeacons know what to display on a notification when in a store?  I am trying to set up a service for my store that i can put different ads in various locations.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but is the best way to do it is have a backend server that i save all of the alert messages to and when a device hits an ibeacon, it requests from the server what to display?  Because the ads vary frequently, I do not want to hard-code the messages in the app.

Is it possible to have the app trigger a server when it hit an i beacon in the background?

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

An iBeacon advertisement is just a UUID, plus a "major" and "minor" value. There is also an RSSI signal that can be used to calibrate distance estimation based on radio signal strength. Nothing else.

Yes, you should implement a back-end server.

When you register for beacon notifications, and indicate that you want them even from the background, your app gets called when the system detects that the device has entered the beacon region. If your app was in the background then the notification will come in with your app still in the background.

From the background your only real option is to display a local notification to the user and hope that he/she slides on the notification to wake up the device and bring your app to the foreground. If the user does not do that then after a few seconds (5, based on my testing) your app goes back to suspended animation until something else wakes it up.

Once you get to the foreground, you could send a request to your remote server announcing that the user has entered such-and-such a beacon region. The server could then send you information that you could present to the user. You probably want your server to use web services, so it 
would likely respond to you in JSON or XML.

Since you only have a few seconds of background processing time before your app goes to sleep, I don't think you would have time to reliably send a request to the server, get back and answer, and formulate a local notification to the user with server-based info in it.

If you did want a server-based message based on entering a beacon region you would need to send your info to the server from the background, then have the server post a push notification to your device. The push notification could contain the specific alert for that beacon.